# How to show to date while using before for java.util.Date.before

Tags: java, date

I need your help in getting the value of the to date while retrieving the list of the months which are between two dates.

In my Code I am using:

```
String date1 = "JAN-2015";
String date2 = "APR-2015";

DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");

Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar finishCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
  beginCalendar.setTime(formater.parse(date1));
  finishCalendar.setTime(formater.parse(date2));
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
String date =     formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
   }
```

The above code will show the list:

```
Jan-2015
Feb-2015
Mar-2015
```

So how can I add also the to date which is `Apr-2015` to it as it is performing the `.before()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `compareTo()` method.

```
while (beginCalendar.compareTo(finishCalendar) <= 0) {
    String date = formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
    beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
}
```

The value of `beginCalendar.compareTo(finishCalendar)` is 0 when `beginCalendar` is equal to `finishCalendar` and less than 0 when `beginCalendar` is before `finishCalendar`.

If you only want to use `before()` method, you have to add one date, either the first or last date, at the outside of the while loop.

Comment: but the OP wants the `.before()` method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String date = formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
//Add this line before the loop So that you get the first data.
while (beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)) {
   beginCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); // increment before getting data.
   String date = formater.format(beginCalendar.getTime()).toUpperCase();
}
```

The main change that was done on your loop is that we increment the Calendar before we collect the String date. This is done to accommodate your condition. When the `beginCalendar` variable is `MAR-2015` it goes to checking condition of the loop resulting in `beginCalendar.before(finishCalendar)` returning `true`.

Comment: it is skipping Jan-2015

Comment: @99maas did you add my first line It is there to print `JAN-2015`